# Oracle trigger to purge old records

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle11g

I'm looking to create a trigger or some other Oracle mechanism to delete old records from a table. The table in question has a "date creted" DateTime column. I'd like to periodically delete rows that are a month old. Does oracle support "periodic tasks", or can/should this be accomplished by an Insert/Update trigger. I don't think that I can modify other rows in a tablewhen a trigger is triggering on that same table.

Is something like this best handled programatically? I am accessing the database through a .NET application and am thinking it might be best to mantain this programmaticly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at DBMS_SCHEDULER.  It will let you set up scheduled jobs.

Official Docs:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_sched.htm

Helpful summary with examples:  http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_scheduler.html